# Echo out a variable like cat in a string

Tags: bash

I have a sql statement that results in a little table of values.
I have to look at it every day can compare it to yesterdays.
I am sick of doing this.

```
/big/database/v10.2.0.2.0-32bit/bin/sqlplus -S casper/secret@wowmomdb2 @/home/casper/installed.sql
```

So I made a little script.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
dayofweek=$(/bin/date +%w)
today=$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d)
if [ $dayofweek == 1 ] ; then
   yesterday=$(/bin/date -d "3 days ago" +%Y%m%d)
   else
   yesterday=$(/bin/date -d "1 day ago" +%Y%m%d)
fi

invoke="/big/database/v10.2.0.2.0-32bit/bin/sqlplus -S "
login="casper/secret@wowmomdb2 "
filter="@/home/casper/installed.sql"
installed="/home/casper/_symbols"

table="$invoke $login $filter"
$table > $installed.$today

echo "Installed Today --------
$installed.$today

Installed Yesterday --------
$installed.$yesterday "  | mail -s "diff exchange installed" casper@big_bank.com

#/big/database/v10.2.0.2.0-32bit/bin/sqlplus -S casper/secret@wowmomdb2 @/home/casper/installed.sql  > /tmp/check_c4_exchange.$today
```

problem is this is want i get mailed to me.

```
Installed Today--------
/home/casper/_symbols.20141104
Installed Yesterday----
/home/casper/_symbols.20141105
```

What i want is todays and yesterdays little table printed out and emailed to me so I can look at it in the morning.
I want the tables catted out.  _ but i don't want to use all kinds of echos - like you know echo out each line.
~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$installed.$today` is the name of a file.  You want the contents of the file.  Try:

```
echo "Installed Today --------
$(cat $installed.$today)

Installed Yesterday --------
$(cat $installed.$yesterday) "
```

#### More Efficient Alternative

If you are using `bash`, then it is not necessary to use `cat`:

```
echo "Installed Today --------
$(<$installed.$today)

Installed Yesterday --------
$(<$installed.$yesterday) "
```

This approach avoids the need to spawn subshells in which to run `cat`, making it more efficient.

Comment: Suggest swapping the alternative to the main solution to avoid spawning of additional subshell.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin OK.  I added text to make it more clear that, for `bash`, that is the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach files by using `mutt` instead of `mail` (other programs may be available on your system too):

```
echo "..." | mutt -s "diff exchange installed" \
  -a $installed.$today -a $installed.$yesterday casper@big_bank.com
```